# Cannot Get a new Radiant Quest from Companions in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have completed the Companions questline and am trying to remove my lycanthropy. I have been trying to get a Radiant Quest from either Farkas or Vilkas, but all members of the faction say that I have an active quest with Vilkas, although there are no Companions quest in my list. I am 100% positive of that.

How can I get past this to the purify quests or is there another way to cure the disease?

Answer (score 2):

Im Not 100% This Will Help But...

According To The Wiki You Need

- Must have at least one Glenmoril Witch Head in inventory.
- Must complete at least 1 Radiant Quest from Farkas or Vilkas, after
  completing Glory of the Dead and having Glenmoril Witch Heads in
  inventory.

If That Doesn't Help The Wiki (Link Below) Will Have A Bug List It Will Help Find Out What You Need To Do To Fix It

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Purity_%28Quest%29

EDIT: It May Be This Bug

There appears to be a bug when you accept Vilkas's Purity quest before Farkas. The quest status will switch to the Completed even though you haven't completed it. Also Vilkas will not follow you to Ysgramor's Tomb. To resolve this, accept and finish Farkas's Purity quest first and be sure that the quest giver is following you the whole way through.

Source: Same As Above

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt the same as my problem. I have the heads in my inventory but it says I have already accepted a job for vilkas. However I have no companions radiant quests listed in my quest log or listed as completed after glory of the dead. So there is no quest they just seem to be stuck on that dialouge. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Did You Look Though The Bug List?

Comment: Yea but none seem to pertain to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a quest to cure yourself of lycantropy, just go to the brazier in Ysgramor's tomb and burn a witch's head.

The 2 Purity quests are to cure Farkas and Vilkas.

Comment: @Add13 I don't think that's how it works, I got my Purity quests inside the Jorrvaskr (or however you spell it) from Vilkas and Farkas, not by tricking them to coming to the tomb. The question, as I understand it, is about curing yourself, not them.

Comment: The only times you can cure yourself at the brazier is after you cure Kodlak (and this is sometimes glitched and not possible) or after you finish either Vilkas or Farkas's purity, whichever one you do last. You need to do both to cure yourself and if you dont cure yourself after this you will no longer be able to cure yourself.

Comment: That's not how it worked for me. Also, you can't cure the brothers before curing Kodlak.

Comment: I know. And the brazier only owrks after glory of the dead or after finishing both purity quests. At no other point. Check here. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Werewolves#Cure

Comment: In that case you should be able to cure yourself at the brazier, since you haven't started either of the Purity quests yet.

Comment: Nope brazier won't work. It seems that it is a common glitch and you can cure yourself after purity quests but I cant start those either unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. Don't suppose going back to a previous save is an option?

Comment: Lol ummm I kinda enjoyed being a werewolf back then so to reload a save back to where this started Id drop about 50 levels. Yea you can see why im kind of in a bind here.