# Companions will no longer give me radiant quests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot Get a new Radiant Quest from Companions in Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73395/cannot-get-a-new-radiant-quest-from-companions-in-skyrim)

I have completed all the Companion's major quests and did a single radiant quest to go fetch a family heirloom. After that I started doing other quests and stuff and left the Companions to themselves for a bit. I then married Aela the Huntress and moved her into my Whiterun house.

Since Dawnguard introduced werewolf perks and stuff I decided I wanted to do the quests to get the totems. However, I now have no options to get a quest from anyone in the companions, and don't have the miscellaneous quest to talk to them for work, either.

I'm still a werewolf and I'm carrying the Glenmoril Witch heads. I know some people have been having the companions tell them they have a quest for one of them, but I have no option to get a quest. Have tried having them as my followers but that doesn't help.

Comment: I believe Aela is the companion who gives the totem quest. I'm not sure if marriage changes her ability to give out quests, but that's all I could think of.

Comment: Aela is the companion who's supposed to hand out the quests, and marriage isn't supposed to change that. But none of the Companions will give me any more quests!

Comment: What platform are you playing on? This is so we'll know if PC-only console commands or mod fixes are possible solutions.

Comment: PC yeah. I've tried the console commands to set the quest to the correct stage, but to no avail. Sadly this game was lost in a batch that got corrupted due to a modding incident :(

Comment: I voted to close this question as per [this meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans).